# one-to-one joined table cascade deletion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-one

I have a cascade deletion issue with a unidirectional one-to-one association on a join table. For example:

The xml declaration is:

```
<class name="Person">
<id name="id" column="personId">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
<join table="PersonAddress" 
    optional="true">
    <key column="personId" 
        unique="true"/>
    <many-to-one name="address"
        column="addressId" 
        not-null="true"
        unique="true"/>
</join>
</class>

<class name="Address">
<id name="id" column="addressId">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
</class>
```

The table is

```
create table Person ( personId bigint not null primary key )
create table PersonAddress ( personId bigint not null primary key, addressId bigint not null   unique )
create table Address ( addressId bigint not null primary key )
```

I want to achieve when person is deleted from person table, the person in personAddress table is also deleted by configurating Hibernate XML declaration. I searched everywhere and could not find a solution. The last choice is manually code the deletion, but I don't like it if Hibernate can support it. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I've never used XML config for hibernate, but isn't there a cascade option under the `<join>` element?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add the cascade to the many-to-one element:

```
<many-to-one name="address"
    column="addressId" 
    not-null="true"
    unique="true"
    cascade="delete"
```

/>

Comment: Thanks, will test out and let you know.

Comment: @Vlad-Mihalcea Cascading deletes from the many side is undefined in the JPA spec and is strongly discouraged. Is it not the case for pure hibernate?

Comment: It is discouraged for child/parent associations, where the parent has a OneToMany side to the child. We are talking about OneToOne associations here. The Hibernate XML configs don't have a dedicated one-to-one namespace, so you have to use a many-to-one config with the unique attribute set to "true".

Comment: @Vlad, interesting, the casecade deletion works even without setting cascade="delete". When the Person is deleted from Person table, personAddress record is also automatically deleted.